# C# Insert block of code to every aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-analytics

I'm having a web application project which is running .NET 4.0. I've plenty of .aspx page and now I would like to add in a block of script code to all the .aspx page header, for example Google Analytics.

I know there is a solution to do is add in every single page, but I would like to know is there any other's way to do this instead modify every single .aspx page?

*My header is not runat server

I got an idea to do but not sure it's work or not.

- Get the page class in Global.asax
- Get the output stream from the page class.
- Insert the Google Analytics code in the HTML header.

I couldn't get the Page.Response in the Global.asax as I tried in the Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute & also Application_EndRequest. Does anyone know is this work and how it's work?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: you are trying to reinvent master pages (WebForms) or _layout files (ASP.Net MVC)... You may want to check if existing functionality works for your before diving into parsing raw streams...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would like to invent into the web forms page, there is no issued for using master page in .aspx. How about those .aspx page that not using any master page. For example, there are 50+ pages not using master page, is very hard to maintain if I'm going to insert the code by every single page.

Comment: Your definition of "hard to maintain" is strange for me... For me using standard solution - master page -  is much easier to maintain (by you or anyone else) than some custom code parsing unknown streams at very rarely used part of ASP.Net pipeline and trying to insert HTML into correct place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). This is the ASP.NET way of putting the same content on multiple pages without repeating yourself.

Comment: is there other ways that not using master pages?

Comment: You could use [response filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

All of our aspx pages code-behind classes inherit from the same base class, which allows us to inject standard client side elements (controls, script, etc) into every page using a single point of control.

Our design was implemented before the advent of master pages, but while it could possibly be converted to a master-page design, we have found this implementation to be extremely flexible and responsive to changing needs.

For example, we have two completely separate application designs (different skin, some different behavior) that is based off of the same code base and page sets. We were able to dynamically swap out banners and other UI and script elements by simple modifications to the base class in order to support this without having to duplicate every page.

Unfortunately, if you want the script to be in the head element, you will need to ensure that they are all marked as runat=server.

Our base class itself inherits from Page, so it can intercept all of the page's events and act on them either instead of or in addition to the inheriting classes (we actually have internal overrideable methods that inheritors should use instead of the page events in order to ensure order of execution).

This is our (VB) code for adding script to the header (in the Page's LoadComplete method):

```
    ' sbscript is a stringbuilder that contains all of the javascript we want to place in the header
    Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(sbScript.ToString))
```

If it is not possible to change the heads to runat server, you could look into ClientScriptManager method [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bahh2fef%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which places the script at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic page with the header with the custom code such as Google analytics and have the other pages inherit from that. It will facilitate two things: 
1) In case you ever want to change the custom code you will only have to do it in one place
2) No repetitive code hence more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing on a legacy app that we're trying to decommission. I need to display a popup on all the old pages to nag users to update their bookmarks to use the new sites, without forcing them to stop using the legacy site (yet). It is not worth the time to convert the site to run on a master page when I can just plop in a popup script, since this whole thing is getting retired soon. The main new site uses a master page, which obviously simplifies things there.

I have this line in a file that has some various constants in it.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly RetirementNagScript As String = "<Script Language='javascript'> alert('[app name] is being retired and will be shut down [in the near future]. Please update your bookmarks and references to the following URL: [some URL]'); </script>"
```

Then I am inserting it in Global.asax, in Application_PostAcquireRequestState:

```
Response.Write(Globals.RetirementNagScript)
```

Hopefully this is useful to you; I still need to be able to present a clickable URL to the user that way, on each page of the legacy site, and JS alert doesn't do that for me.